# Override Authorization header

Tags: jmeter

I am doing a testing

1. I have setup an HTTP Authorization Manager to manage my Basic Browser Authentication. This is declared before my HTTP request - making each HTTP request header contains

   ```
   Authorization: SOMETHING sOmeGibber1SHCOdes...
   ```
2. As some point in my testing, I need to add a new entry in the Authorization header. So I created an HTTP header Manager and added something like:

   ```
   Authorization: somethingElse @n0therGibber15hC0de...
   ```

   and this overrides my existing header setup by my HTTP Authorization Manager

**Question:**
If I need both Authorization header - is there a workaround?

**Additional info:**
I tried extracting the values using regext extractor and concatenate the strings in the HTTP Header manager... does't seem to work. I think simply copying the header created by HTTP Authorization manager  and putting it directly to the HTTP Header Manager is not being recognized as an authentication by jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Please be informed about [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) concept

- If HTTP Authorization Manager lives **at the same level** with the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers - it will be applied to **all of them**
- If HTTP Authorization Manager (or HTTP Header Manager) is added **as a child** of a particular HTTP Request sampler - it will be applied to **this sampler only**

So you can "override" the "global" [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header value by adding a HTTP Header Manager as a child of the particular request and defining the header there:

[image]